# How do I change a single column's values into another tables headers

Tags: sql, pivot

I need to change/pivot a single column's values into another tables headers, eg:
I have a table as below:

| headers |
| --- |
| Food |
| Drink |

I need to change/pivot this to get the following result (an empty table with headers):

| Food | Drink |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
|  |  |

or is it maybe possible to select a column as a select statement eg:
select 'a' as (select headers from table where headers = 'Food'),
'b' as (select headers from table where headers = 'Drink')
from random_table

I have tried something like this but it does not work.

Please help

Comment: Is there other information in the "headers" table?  What you're taking about cannot be done in straight SQL.  If you have rows with a column "Type", you can certainly do `WHERE Type = 'Food'`.

Comment: More information will be helpful, like what database is you used?

Comment: I also need to mention, when I have this table, I need to be able to insert into this table, eg. values for Food and Drink.

Comment: @TimRoberts, no other info in the headers table, only that one column. And to make it even more difficult, the words 'food' and 'drink' will be dynamically pulled from other selects. Thats also why I asked the 2nd question, can I use a select statement's result as a column header, that will also solve my problem if I cannot pivot like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is just not the right way to design a database.  The column names should be known in advance and fixed.  Let's assume these are categories, and you want item names and price information.  You might have:

```
CREATE TABLE comestibles (
    name TEXT,
    category TEXT,
    price INTEGER
);
```

Now I can have, for example:

```
|--------|-------|---|
| ham    | food  | 15|
| potato | food  | 9 |
| coke   | drink | 4 |
| tea    | drink | 4 |
```

And you can make requests like

```
SELECT name,price FROM comestibles WHERE category='food';
```

Now you can add different categories to your heart's content without requiring a redesign of your table and huge modifications to your code.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I think I am approaching this whole thing wrong, I will first continue a bit before commenting if needed. Thanks fir the assistance so far though.